# How to make SliverAppBar overgrow inside NestedScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `NestedScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` and a `TabBar`. The scrolling works well when scrolling down scrollable content like `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView`, but whenever I try to scroll up and get the SliverAppBar to overgrow, nothing happens.

In the `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` of the `SliverAppBar` I am overwriting the following method like so:

```
@override
OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration get stretchConfiguration => 
    OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration();
```

This is the class of the screen I am talking about:

```
class ProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {

  const ProfileScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.userId
  });

  final String userId;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends ConsumerState<ProfileScreen> with 
TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final AsyncValue<List<BasicEventModel>> eventsAsync = 
ref.watch(profileEventsProvider(widget.userId));

    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: Themes.systemUiOverlayStyle(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Themes.color(context, light: Palette.white, dark: 
Palette.gray900),
        body: ExtendedNestedScrollView(
          pinnedHeaderSliverHeightBuilder: () => topPadding + kToolbarHeight,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
            ProfileAppBar()
          ],
          body: Column(
            children: [
              ProfileTabBar(controller: tabController),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: tabController,
                  children: [
                    eventsAsync.when(
                      data: (List<BasicEventModel> events) => 
ProfileEventsList(events: events),
                      error: (Object e, StackTrace s) => 
_eventsText('profile_events_error'.tr()), 
                      loading: () => const ProfileEventsShimmer()
                    ),
                    // other Widgets for the other tabs
                  ]
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you may like SliverPersistenseHeader

Comment: I am already using a SliverPersistentHeader since I am implementing SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate as said in the question.